# Search giving no results

Tags: magento2, search

Front end product search not working for any keywords. Advanced search works if you don't use product name or description. Custom attr. works, as does SKU.

Every time you search you get 'Your search returned no results.'.

Cleared caches, re-indexed multiple times.

I note that catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1 is empty (not sure if it should be).

It was working a week ago and we've changed no files. **There was a server crash**.

No errors in var/reports and the logs aren't displaying anything.

All products visible on the front end in categories and working as normal.

I'm running around in circles! Has anybody encountered zero search results before? There's 600 odd products, Magento 2.2.1

Have also tried changing 'name' attribute details, disabling and re-enabling products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug never got resolved for us in 2.2.1 but resolved itself after upgrading to a newer Magento 2 version (In our case v2.2.7).